# Possibility of using 3rd-party app to open Uber app then going back to 3rd-party app on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api, deeplink

I'm developing an iOS app that embeds UberRides feature. However, all of the example codes I can find online is about opening up Uber app after request button is pushed in my own app. I'm wondering if there is a way to tracking the action of user in Uber app so when user confirm his/her ride, my own app will know that action happens and open up again.

Comment: Where did you find example codes for opening up uber app, i couldn't find any ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported, unfortunately. For iOS 9 users however, they are able to go back to your app using the back button link in the status bar after your app launches Uber.